# Markov chain of a given limit state

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $X$ be a finite set and $M$ a Markov chain over it, one can find its limit state vector(s) $v$ under certain conditions. I'm curious about the converse: Given a vector $v$, how to find all Markov chains $M$ such that $v$ is one and the only one limit state of $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below is incorrect (see comments)

---

Here is something that works if $v$ has no zero entries. Let $D$ denote the diagonal matrix
$$
D = \operatorname{diag}(v) = \pmatrix{v_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && v_n}.
$$
If $P$ is a row-stochastic matrix, then $P$ is the transition matrix with unique stationary distribution $v$ if and only if the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ of $P^T$ has geometric multiplicity (GM) $1$ and $v$ is an associated eigenvector.

This is the equivalent to the condition that $DP^TD^{-1}$ and $[DP^TD^{-1}]^T = D^{-1}PD$ are [doubly-stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) with eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ having GM $1$.

Putting all this together: $P$ is the transition matrix of a Markov chain with the desired property if and only if there exists a doubly stochastic matrix $Q$ with $\operatorname{rank}(Q - I) = n-1$ for which $P = DQD^{-1}$.

If you are simply interested in generating a random such $P$, note that a randomly generated doubly stochastic matrix $Q$ will work "with probability $1$".

Comment: Nice trick on turning $v$ into $D$! Thanks! .. could be a digression, but does it also work "with probability 1" if I require $P$ to be a reversible markov chain?

Comment: I haven’t said anything about enforcing the requirements for reversibility. In fact, I suspect that there is exactly one reversible markov chain with the given stationary distribution

Comment: Actually that statement about uniqueness is definitely wrong. In any case, the reversibility condition changes things significantly

Comment: I'm looking at a specific [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4779), in which the final vector is "deformed". The authors went on demonstrating a way to find a (deformed) reversible Markov chain, using the "auxiliary variable method".. I hope that's unique in any sense.. perhaps this deserves to be another thread.

Comment: I think it deserves to be another thread

Comment: If $P$ is a stochastic matrix (row stochastic as standard) then $P\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$  and $\mathbf v^T P = \mathbf v^T$.... but you write that $ D^{-1}PD$ is 'doubly stochastic'... if so this means $\mathbf 1=D^{-1}PD \mathbf 1 $; left multiplication by $D$ gives $\mathbf v = D\mathbf 1 = PD\mathbf 1 = P\mathbf v$.  But this implies that $\mathbf v = \mathbf 1$ for an irreducible chain (which of course should be the focus and the problem reduces to a collection of irreducible chains in any case), i.e. it assumes that $P$ was doubly stochastic to begin with.  Did I miss something here?

Comment: @user8675309 That was a pretty bad oversight on my part. Indeed, if $P$ was row-stochstic, then $D^{-1}PD$ is column-stochastic but not necessarily row-stochastic

Comment: FWIW I had similar initial thoughts -- though I first reach for $D^\frac{1}{2}$ as a way of symmetrizing the Perron vector (see e.g. the *very end* of this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703911/reference-request-convergence-for-periodic-markov-chains/3704687#3704687 ) .