# Uniqueness of reversible Markov chain?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, markov-chains

Let $M$ be a Markov chain over a finite set. Call $M$ to be irreducible if there is one and only one dominant eigenvalue $1$. In this case, there's only one stable vector $v$.

I was interested in the opposite direction. Namely, given any vector $v$, can one find all irreducible Markov chains whose stable vector is $v$? This is answered by [Ben](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849432/markov-chain-of-a-given-limit-state/) using a clever trick that turns the vector $v$ into a diagonal matrix. So, there are many such Markov chains.

I wonder if one can still characterize if an extra condition, reversibility, is imposed. Here, by saying $M$ to be reversible I mean that

$$
v(x) M(x,y) = v(y) M(y,x) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall x,y \in X
$$

#### Question

Given a vector $v$, what are all reversible and irreducible Markov chains $M$ whose final state is $v$?

I have a sense that such $M$ is unique, and will demonstrate a **process-state correspondence**. But I don't have a proof.

Comment: My previous answer is incorrect; sorry about that

Comment: No worries Ben. Thanks for the attempt! I have a sense of that it should be unique.. but I haven't seen a way to prove it.

Comment: it won’t generally be unique, as you can see in the case where $v$ is the constant vector. In this case, any symmetric doubly stochastic matrix encodes a reversible chain with the right stationary distribution