# Proving this matrix limit

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, matrix-calculus, stochastic-matrices

> Let $A$ be a stochastic matrix. Prove that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum^{k-1}_{i=0}A^i$$ exists.

---

This is my attempt.

Let

$$T^{-1}AT =   
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A_1 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & \ddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & A_m \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then,

$$ T^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{k}\sum^{k-1}_{i=0}A^i \right)T = \frac{1}{k}\sum^{k-1}_{i=0}(T^{-1}AT)^i =\begin{bmatrix}
    B_1 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & \ddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & B_m \\
  \end{bmatrix} $$

where $A_1, \dots, A_m, B_1, \dots, B_m$ are Jordan blocks, and $$B_j = \frac{1}{k}\sum^{k-1}_{i=0}A_j^i$$ Since $A$ is a stochastic matrix, then its maximum eigenvalue in magnitude is at most $1$. Then, the diagonal entries of $B_j$ converge to $0$ as $k \to \infty$, whenever the eigenvalue of that block matrix is not $1$, and converges to $1$ when the eigenvalue is $1$. How can I prove that the elements that are not in the diagonal of $B_j$ also converge?

Comment: $A_k$ are Jordan blocks (not $B_k$). You have to prove that the arithmetic means of Jordan blocks have limit.  Write down a few powers of Jordan block and then use the fact that all eigenvalues (aside from 1) are less than (in module) 1.

Comment: Your observations so far are insufficient. For example, with 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1},
$$
we find that 
$$
\frac 1{k}\sum_{i=0}^k A^i = \pmatrix{1 & (k-1)/2\\0 & 1},
$$ 
which does not have a limit

Comment: @BenGrossmann  I think 'stochastic' here means the sum of each row is one.

Comment: @WillJagy Sure, but my point here is that knowing that each block $A_j$ is associated with an eigenvalue with magnitude at most $1$ is not enough information to deduce that $\frac 1k \sum_{i=0}^k J^k$ converges where $J = T^{-1}AT$ is the Jordan form of $A$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann  good, I wasn't sure what you meant.

Comment: Whenever I see a problem involving $\,(I+A+A^2+\ldots)\,$ I wonder what happens if I multiply it by $(I-A)\;$

Comment: @greg In this case we run into a bit of a snag doing so because $I-A$ is singular

Comment: To follow up my first comment, we also need to worry about the algebraic multiplicity of other eigenvalues with magnitude $1$. For example, the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-1&1\\0&0&-1}
$$
Satisfies
$$
\frac 1k \sum_{i=0}^k A^i = (I - A)^{-1} \frac 1k (I - A^{k+1}) ,
$$
but the $1,3$ entry of $\frac 1k (I - A^{k+1})$ is given by $(-1)^{k+1}(k+1)$, which fails to converge as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Multiplying by $(I-A)$ creates an eigenvalue problem in terms of the columns of the unknown matrix.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: $A$ in your example is not stochastic. However, I agree on that $(I-A)$ might not be invertible.

Comment: @Salcio: I did that for the diagonals, but for the elements not in the diagonal I get sums involving combinatorial sums that I don't know how to handle.

Comment: @Keio203 See my comment to Will Jagy. The point is that we need to know about the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalues (of maximal magnitude) in order to be able to show convergence from the Jordan form

Comment: @Keio203 Ultimately, you'll need the fact that if $A$ is irreducible, then every eigenvalue of $A$ with magnitude $1$ has algebraic multiplicity $1$. This result is proved in "Matrix  analysis and applied linear algebra" by Carl Meyer on page 676 (Chapter 8, Section 3).

Comment: @greg has the right idea here.  The most direct approach is with telescoping, albeit with a tweak to accomodate Perron vectors.  I gave a proof here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703911/reference-request-convergence-for-periodic-markov-chains/3704687#3704687

Comment: @user8675309: In your proof, how can it be guaranteed that $\pi$ is unique?

Comment: @Keio203 it isn't clear what your question means.  If it is an analytic question: then my link computes the limit and in a metric space that is necessarily unique.  If it is an algebraic question about $\pi$  this follows by irreducibility of $P$ and Perron-Frobenius theory so $\pi$ lives in a 1-dimensional subspace.